# unique_ptr for non-polymorphic derived class with C++20 destroying operator delete

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, delete-operator, c++20

C++20 new feature of ***destroying operator delete***, allows to "hook" the call to the destructor and "replace" it with our own operation (e.g. theoretically, calling the proper destructor of a derived class).

Is it possible to use *destroying operator delete*, to allow a `unique_ptr<A>` to hold a pointer to an actual non-polymorphic derived class of `A` (i.e. no virtual destructor in `A`) without a need for a *custom deleter*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In fact it resembles a use case raised in [P0722](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0722r1.html) for *Dynamic dispatch without vptrs*.

Before C++20 A `unique_ptr<A>` holding a pointer to a derived class of `A` required either:

- a *virtual destructor* in `A` -- OR
- a *custom deleter*

The C++20 specification added new delete operator - [*destroying operator delete*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation#def:operator_delete,destroying): calling delete on a static type which is different from the dynamic type to be deleted, does not fall in the undefined behavior case, if the selected deallocation function is a destroying operator delete, as detailed in [[expr.delete](§7.6.2.9/3)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3) (emphasis mine):

> In a single-object delete expression, if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type **and the selected deallocation function [...] is not a destroying operator delete**, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. [...]

So, the option of using *destroying operator delete* for this purpose is valid.

For example, if we know that `A` would never be instantiated and that `unique_ptr<A>` would actually always hold a pointer of type `A_Proxy`, we can perform a *down cast* in the *destroying operator delete* by using `static_cast` and call the proper destructor (the same could have been done in a *custom deleter*, which can be waived now).

```
class A {
    friend struct A_Proxy;
    std::string s; // just an example of a member managed at A's level
    A(const char* str): s(str) {}
    ~A() {}
public:
    // Note: this is the destroying operator delete, as introduced in C++20
    void operator delete(A *p, std::destroying_delete_t);
    static std::unique_ptr<A> create(); // no need for a custom deleter
    void foo() const;
};
```

A simple derived class *A_Proxy*:

```
struct A_Proxy: A {
    A_Proxy(): A("A_Proxy") {}
    ~A_Proxy() { /* do anything that is required at the proxy level */ }
    void foo() const {
        std::cout << "A_Proxy::foo()" << std::endl;         
    }
};
```

With the implementations of `A`:

```
void A::operator delete(A *p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
    // in this example we know for sure p is of type A_Proxy*
    ::delete static_cast<A_Proxy*>(p);
    // ^ call the global ::delete to avoid recursion
}

std::unique_ptr<A> A::create() {
    return std::make_unique<A_Proxy>(); // without the need for a custom deleter
}

void A::foo() const {
    static_cast<const A_Proxy*>(this)->foo();
}
```

Main:

```
int main () {
    auto a = A::create();
    auto b = a.release();
    a = std::unique_ptr<A>(b);
    a->foo();
}
```

[The code above - with a *destroying operator delete*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39ebb4bc975b3a5a).

---

**It is to be noted however that there is no real magic here.** Using a *custom deleter* would result with quite a similar code. Note also that most if not all implementations of `unique_ptr` would have a bare pointer size for a [stateless custom deleter](https://dev.krzaq.cc/post/you-dont-need-a-stateful-deleter-in-your-unique_ptr-usually), which can be used for this purpose.

[The same code as above - but with a *custom deleter*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef5bfa5c02ff33ac).
<= Note that the size of the `unique_ptr` with the *custom deleter* in this implementation is the same as a bare pointer.

---

Above technique can be relevant also in cases where there is more than a single possible cast, by using a proper *type flag* in the base class, for example:

```
void A::operator delete(A *p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
    if(p->type == "A") {
        ::delete p;
    }
    else if(p->type == "B") {
        ::delete static_cast<B*>(p);
    }
    else if(p->type == "C") {
        ::delete static_cast<C*>(p);
    }
    else {
        throw "unsupported type";
    }
}
```

**And again**, both approaches - the [*destroying operator delete* approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb9ceb022f47817d) and the [*custom deleter* approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef35d8f6107f22e7) would result with quite a similar code and a bare pointer size for the `unique_ptr` (in the *destroying operator delete* approach the `unique_ptr` size is **ensured** to be of bare pointer size, in the *custom deleter* approach **it would most probably be**, if you implement the deleter properly, and depending on the actual implementation of `unique_ptr`).

Comment: “unique_ptr with a custom deleter, which has bigger size” - that’s wrong, in most (if not all) libraries you will not have a bigger size if the deleter is an empty type, which can be used to implement all deleters in your answer.

Comment: @Dani taken and fixed

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem by providing own version of `make_unique` instead trying use some new feature from C++20.

```cpp
template<typename Base, typename T, typename ...Args>
auto base_make_unique(Args&&...args) ->
        typename std::enable_if<!std::has_virtual_destructor<Base>::value,
                                std::unique_ptr<Base, void(*)(Base*)>
                            >::type
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Base, void(*)(Base*)>{
        new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...},
        &has_virtual_destructor_deleter<Base, T>
    };
}

template<typename Base, typename T, typename ...Args>
auto base_make_unique(Args&&...args) ->
        typename std::enable_if<std::has_virtual_destructor<Base>::value,
                                std::unique_ptr<Base>
                            >::type
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Base>{new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E7Tasv

Comment: That's a cool approach, however having a custom deleter has the size price for the `unique_ptr` which is waived with the _destroying operator delete_ approach.

Comment: there is no choice you have to hide somewhere information about deleting process. There are possible two places: side by side to pointer (like in example) or side by side to object (this is how make_shared works it stores deleter and reference counter in same memory block as created object). Since `unique_ptr` is unique first option is better because of memory alignment. Second option can consume more memory.

Comment: the _destroying operator delete_ approach doesn't increase the size of the smart pointer nor does it add any additional memory aside the object itself. It is just a function residing in the code segment and being statically linked.

Comment: @AmirKirsh You can make the custom deleter stateless (so it won't use any extra memory), if you expect `std::unique_ptr<A>` to **always** point to `A_Proxy`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that's correct, it can work in that case. However not for a generic deleter as presented in Marek's answer, a functor would not work there: https://godbolt.org/z/ssqYK5

Comment: @AmirKirsh Yep, a generic deleter must be stateful, but the equivalent generic destroying delete also requires state (in this case stored in the base class, which you called a "type flag").

Comment: @HolyBlackCat put the size aside, it's two different approaches. If you have several different derived classes for A, with the custom deleter approach you couldn't have a generic unique_ptr that is able to hold any derived. You can achieve that with a virtual dtor or with the destroying operator delete.

Comment: @AmirKirsh *"couldn't have a generic unique_ptr that is able to hold any derived"* But you can? With a stateful deleter, like this answer shows.